# Why does one person use Plus-que-parfait while the other uses Passé composé?

Tags: temps-grammatical

> X : Vous arrivez au bon moment. J’**avais prévu** une petite activité que nous pourrions partager.
>
> Y : Qu’**avez**-vous **prévu** ?

An intriguing mismatch of tense – I wonder why they don’t need to stick to one tense or the other:

> « J’**avais prévu** » & « Qu’**aviez**-vous **prévu** »
>
> or : « J’**ai prévu** » & « Qu’**avez**-vous **prévu** »

Comment: Are answers in French ok ? I can translate mine if you want.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Not to worry! Actually, I'd prefer an explanation in French. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that it is only a matter of politeness. The tense that should technically be used is the *passé composé*, while the *plus-que-parfait* is used only for being polite and not sounding like you're demanding something from the other person.

See the [CRNTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plus-que-parfait) :

> [Pour atténuer un propos, par politesse, à la place du prés. de l'ind.] « Mais Emma, se tournant vers madame Homais : − On m'avait fait venir » (Flaubert, *Mme Bovary*).

(instead of « on m'a fait venir » which is what she really means)

---

The two sentences you quote correspond to the two speakers using the same register :

> « J'avais prévu » & « Qu’aviez-vous prévu » – Both are being very polite.
>
> « J’ai prévu » & « Qu’avez-vous prévu » – Both are speaking normally.

The sentence you have trouble with corresponds to the first person being polite and the second person not feeling a need for being over-polite. It is natural (in my opinion) that the first speaker be polite to not sound demanding (about the « petite activité ») while the second one does not need to be polite about something that the other is offering.

Comment: I like your closing discussion about how the mixing of these two tenses can be explained by how the need for a polite tone is greater for the person proposing the plan than for the one responding to it. From another angle, is it possible that someone responding to a politely formed (*plus-que-parfait*) proposition with the *passé composé* (or even more so w/the present [Que prévois-tu?]) is implying his/her initial blind agreement with/enthusiasm for whatever the plan is & could be seen as actually being more polite (or at least more positive) than a response using the *plus-que-parfait*?

Comment: Quite possibly. « Qu'aviez-vous prévu ? » sounds like you're not ready for it.

Comment: @styko - not sure about that. I am native and not feeling it. Are you also native? Just to understand if other natives might feel that in this sentence.

Comment: @PapaPoule - IMHO you are reading way too much into this :-) You could be right, but as a practical matter, I don't think the average speaker would be aware of these nuances, if they are there, which I am really not convinced about.

Comment: That's right! Using plus-que-parfait sounds like his proposition stays pending until the interlocutor will accept it. It sounds like the thing is not going to take place unless the other one agrees, that's why it's more polite.

Comment: For my part, I would say that if it feels polite, it's just because it is more elaborate. But frankly, I don't find the difference noticeable enough that we would systematically use one or the other for politeness.

Comment: Yeah - I can hear it, ok, but not 100% clear or something I would systematically pay attention to.

Comment: Frankly, (this is said ***politely), I do not think the explanation for these tenses is overwhelming about politeness. There is also the issue of concordance des temps that comes into play.

Answer (score 2):

En fait, le français laisse une liberté de choix à l'interlocuteur: ce n'est pas parce que j'ai prévu de faire quelque chose que je vais vous l'imposer...

C'est donc une marque de politesse qui signifie « voilà ce que j'ai prévu », mais puisque vous êtes là, bien sûr je propose de faire ce que j'avais prévu, mais je suis ouvert à changer mes plans...

Et bien sûr, puisque l'interlocuteur est bien élevé, il répond de manière positive avec: « qu'avez vous prévu ? » pour affirmer que ce n'est pas parce qu'il est venu que vous devez changer de plan et qu'il est d'accord pour suivre votre plan...

Donc, il n'y a pas là une question de grammaire, mais une question de bienséance... On est vraiment loin des Trumpitudes...

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec cette interprétation. J'ajouterai que la façon de s'exprimer de X ouvre la voie à une interprétation plus en finesse. S'il avait dit ‘j'avais prévu un truc à faire ensemble’ c'eût été moins clair.

Comment: On se passera, en revanche, du commentaire politique.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûre qu'il ne faille résister à tout moment, en étant personellement sous ce joug particulier. Cela dit, quid de la concordance des temps? Cela ne compte plus? :)

Comment: On la casse a l'oral parfois.

Comment: Résister à Trump ici ne va pas avoir beaucoup de résultats, à mon avis...

Answer (score 1):

> *J'ai prévu une activité* => L'activité va probablement se faire.
>
> *J'avais prévu une activité* => Elle ne va probablement pas se faire.

Autre exemple :

> J'avais fait à manger, mais finalement ils ne viendront pas.
>
> J'ai fait à manger, ils vont se régaler !

Donc dire "*J'avais prévu*" permet de ne pas imposer l'activité à l'invité :

> J'avais prévu une activité pour les invités (*mais si ça ne vous intéresse pas vous n'êtes pas obligés de participer*)

Le "*que nous pourrions partager*" insiste sur le "*si vous voulez*", X laisse le choix à Y.

De la même manière, si Y répond "*Qu'aviez-vous prévu ?*" ça sous-entend qu'il ne va pas participer, alors qu'en répondant "*Qu'avez-vous prévu ?*" il indique qu'il est intéressé et implicitement il dit qu'il va participer à l'activité.

Dans une autre situation, il aurait pu dire quelque chose comme :

> On a tellement parlé qu'on n'a pas eu le temps pour votre activité. Qu'aviez-vous prévu ?

Le moment pour faire l'activité est passé, elle ne se fera pas.

C'est bien de la politesse, mais les autres réponses insistent dessus sans réellement expliquer le pourquoi.

Comment: @Frank Oups merci, j'ai corrigé. Fautes de frappes (à force d'éditer, de couper/coller, ...)

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as English, which is not always the case by any means:

A: "You're getting here at the right time [Present]. I had planned [past perfect] a little activity that we can share".

B: What did you plan? [simple past].

X : Vous arrivez au bon moment. J’avais prévu une petite activité que nous pourrions partager.

Y : Qu’avez-vous prévu ?

Je vais  au marcher aujourd'hui [présent]. Mais, j'avais prévu d'y aller il y a deux jours. [plus-que-parfait]. Et peut-être, mon mari y est allé hier. Je ne sais pas.

I'm going to the market today. But I had planned to go there two days ago. Et maybe my husband went there yesterday.

The planning in your example precedes the person's arrival. That's why plus-que-parfait (past perfect) is used here and it would be used in English too. It's completely logical.

Ici, il y une concordance de temps logique. Une action vient avant une autre.

Comment: Peut-être QUE, sounds more idiomatic ;)